# How can I improve the usability/readability of Toad

Tags: toad, usability, readability

I have installed Toad 12.8 and I had a pretty big mistake in executing code.  I executed code out of sequence, despite triple checking my work. Some how the tab I had selected was unselected and another script was ran.  I still wince in embarrassment a week later.

I just wanted to know if there are ways to improve usability/readability of Toad.  For instance, can I highlight the tab I have selected?  Can I review scripts in a viewer to showcase scripts that I have open and manage which have been executed and not?

I have changed the tab style to 'Flat Buttons', which better showcases the script you are viewing among the many you have open, but thats just 1 small change.

Anyone else have options they like to use?  Im not seeing a lot of options here under View Options...

Answer (score 0):

I'm on 12.5. Current tab *is* highlighted (i.e. has a different color than other tabs). You could, though, change the window background color (by default, it is white).

Open "Configure TOAD options" and search for "TAB", you'll find quite a few options in there.

If you want to review what you've executed, navigate to "Query Viewer" tab in the Editor window. Sort results by "Start Time" in descending order and it'll show what you executed, when, how many time was spent on it, how many rows were affected ... quite useful.

As of running code you didn't mean to: well, what can I say? I'm sorry you did that, but - after all - it is you who should pay attention to what you are doing. No highlighting will solve that problem (also know as *we have met the enemy, and it is us*).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  In case anyone searches this, I also found that it helps to push open tabs to the left, not top.  Right click on the tab > Position > Left

Answer (score 0):

Something I like to do to is to change the color of TEST vs PROD in order to make them stand out.  On the session/new connection window, scroll right and you'll see a "color" column. I set PROD connections to Red and TEST to Blue.  Give it a try, maybe you'll like it for a visual reminder for the environment you are working in.  It will change the status bar background color so it's not that intrusive.